# Why is only the half of my object rendered with cycles on blender?

Tags: modeling, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]Im kinda new on blender and I would like to make my first render. The problem is the following. Only the half of the object is « well » rendered and there is a lot of noise on the image. Could you please help me to find out how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: since you are a beginner it would help us most if you just provide your blend file. Else we have to ask a lot of questions and it would be very time consuming to ask you and wait until you answer....

Comment: Where is there a lot of noise in the image? And which half is rendered well? The lower part of the object looks like "Shaded Flat" (it's an option in the Object mode, context menu) and this creates the hard edges. I have no idea what the top of the object is and if it should look like this.